# Replacing strings with integers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to replace any phone number in a column that may consist with the letter o instead of the number 0. Is there any way I can do this?

For example: a `Phone` column that accepts `NVARCHAR` and there are multiple inputs of numbers like this:

```
1-800-9o6o
(962)47l-9o8o
(472)1o4-7o91
```

by multiple I mean 80+

Comment: Please show the desired values

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Why do you need nvarchar for phone numbers? There are exactly zero characters in any phone that require the extended character set.

Comment: @SeanLange, it is a bad practice to store any number that is not going to be used in math calculations as a number. A phone number is text data not numeric. Sometimes you need to add an extension to it. Some places prefer them to be formatted as they are stored. It appears to be that case where teh OP works.

Comment: @HLGEM I was not suggesting the OP store them as a number, not sure how you interpreted my comment as such. But there is no point in using nvarchar for phone numbers when varchar would be more than adequate.

Comment: Thanks Everyone I got it working

Comment: @AlexSalgado if an answer below is correct you should accept it =)

Answer (score 2):

With a simple replace statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

```
Replace(YourColumn, 'o', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function:

```
replace(phone_number, 'o', '0')
```

If you are selecting, then use:

```
select replace(phone_number, 'o', '0') from t;
```

If you need to update the table:

```
update t
set phone_number = replace(phone_number, 'o', '0')
where phone_number like '%o%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replace()`:

```
update t
    set phone = replace(phone, 'o', '0')
    where phone like '%o%';
```

Given your examples, you might also want to change the lower-case "l" to 1:

```
update t
    set phone = replace(replace(phone, 'o', '0'), 'l', '1')
    where phone like '%[ol]%';
```